# How to set tooltip on my JFreeChart?

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am working on a line chart using JFreeChart. I want to set tool tips on my line chart but I am unable to do that on Servlet. So please help me to set tool tips on Servlet?

```
XYSeriesCollection dataset = new XYSeriesCollection();
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

  XYSeries series = new XYSeries("Name"+i);
  for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    series.add(i+j,j+i*j);
  }
  dataset.addSeries(series);
}

JFreeChart chart= ChartFactory.createXYLineChart("Line Chart Demo 2", "X", "Y", dataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true,false);

XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();
plot.setAxisOffset(new RectangleInsets(5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0));
plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);
plot.setDomainGridlinePaint(Color.white);
plot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.white);

XYLineAndShapeRenderer renderer = (XYLineAndShapeRenderer) plot.getRenderer();
renderer.setShapesVisible(true);
renderer.setShapesFilled(true);

Vector<String> ToolTips1 = new Vector<String>();
for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
{
  ToolTips1.add("First: "+j);
}

Vector<String> ToolTips2 = new Vector<String>();
for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
{
  ToolTips2.add("Second: "+j);
}

CustomXYToolTipGenerator generator1 = new CustomXYToolTipGenerator();
generator1.addToolTipSeries(ToolTips1);
CustomXYToolTipGenerator generator2 = new CustomXYToolTipGenerator();
generator2.addToolTipSeries(ToolTips2);

renderer.setSeriesToolTipGenerator(0, generator1);
renderer.setSeriesToolTipGenerator(1, generator2);

renderer.setBaseShape(new Ellipse2D.Double(-3.0, -3.0, 8.0, 8.0));
plot.setRenderer(renderer);

response.setContentType("image/png");
RenderedImage chartImage=chart.createBufferedImage(500,500);
ImageIO.write(chartImage,"png",out);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [ChartFactory constructor](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartFactory.html#createAreaChart%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20org.jfree.data.category.CategoryDataset,%20org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20boolean%29)

```
public static JFreeChart createAreaChart(java.lang.String title,
                     java.lang.String categoryAxisLabel,
                     java.lang.String valueAxisLabel,
                     CategoryDataset dataset,
                     PlotOrientation orientation,
                     boolean legend,
                     boolean tooltips,
                     boolean urls)
```

Creates an area chart with default settings. The chart object returned by this method uses a CategoryPlot instance as the plot, with a CategoryAxis for the domain axis, a NumberAxis as the range axis, and an AreaRenderer as the renderer.

**Parameters:**

- title - the chart title (null permitted).
- categoryAxisLabel - the label for the category axis (null permitted).
- valueAxisLabel - the label for the value axis (null permitted).
- dataset - the dataset for the chart (null permitted).
- orientation - the plot orientation (null not permitted).
- legend - a flag specifying whether or not a legend is required.
- **tooltips - configure chart to generate tool tips?**
- urls - configure chart to generate URLs?

**Returns:**
An area chart.

Answer (score 3):

```
 XYToolTipGenerator xyToolTipGenerator = new XYToolTipGenerator()
 {
     public String generateToolTip(XYDataset dataset, int series, int item)
     {
         Number x1 = dataset.getX(series, item);
         Number y1 = dataset.getY(series, item);
         StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
         stringBuilder.append(String.format("<html><p style='color:#0000ff;'>Serie: '%s'</p>", dataset.getSeriesKey(series)));
         stringBuilder.append(String.format("X:'%d'<br/>", x1.intValue()));
         stringBuilder.append(String.format("Y:'%d'", y1.intValue()));
         stringBuilder.append("</html>");
         return stringBuilder.toString();
     }
 };

 XYLineAndShapeRenderer render = (XYLineAndShapeRenderer) plot.getRenderer();
 render.setBaseToolTipGenerator(xyToolTipGenerator);
```

Comment: If I might make a suggestion, some description of what your code does might help the questioner.

Comment: Thaks @RüdigerHerrmann ! I don't know exactly where is the problem the in  varun's code. But I have a sample code that does what he wants. This might be useful =].

Comment: I upvoted it because the key here is the `setBaseToolTipGenerator()` that is missing in the other answer. But I agree with @RüdigerHerrmann: a bit of text explaining that would have been nice.